# How can I get CMake to find my alternative Boost installation?

Tags: linux, boost, cmake, build-automation, wt

I have installed the most recent version of Boost in `/usr/local` (with includes in `/usr/local/include/boost` and libraries in `/usr/local/lib/boost`) and I am now attempting to install Wt from source, but CMake (version 2.6) can't seem to find the Boost installation. It tries to give helpful suggestions about setting BOOST_DIR and Boost_LIBRARYDIR, but I haven't been able to get it to work by tweaking these variables.

The most recent error message that I get is that it can't find the libraries, but it seems to indicate that it is using "/usr/local/include" for the include path, which isn't correct (and I can't seem to fix it). Is there a solution for this off the top of their head, or do I need to go mucking around inside CMake to figure it out?

Comment: findBoost is hard when the underlying problem is easy, and impossible when the underlying problem is hard. CMake would be wise to add a `useBoost(1.55 /here/is/the/include/dir /here/is/the/lib/dir)` options which bypasses all this fragile logic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816206/cmake-find-package-specify-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging around in CMake and experimenting, I determined that CMake was unhappy with the fact that all of my Boost libraries were contained in `/usr/local/lib/boost` and not `/usr/local/lib`.  Once I soft-linked them back out, the build worked.

Comment: Why does that make a difference?  You define your BOOST_ROOT in CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 48):

You should have a look at `FindBoost.cmake` script, which handles Boost detection and setting up all Boost variables. It typically resides in `/usr/share/cmake-2.6/Modules/`. In it, you will find documentation. For instance:

```
# These last three variables are available also as environment variables:
#
#   BOOST_ROOT or BOOSTROOT      The preferred installation prefix for searching for
#                                Boost.  Set this if the module has problems finding
#                                the proper Boost installation.
#
```

In contrast to BOOST_ROOT, the variables you are referring to are actually variables that are set by the FindBoost module. Note that you don't have to (and probably also don't want to) edit your CMake project configuration to set BOOST_ROOT. Instead, you should use the environment variable, e.g. calling

`# BOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/... ccmake .`

Comment: if you install in /usr/local/boost, shouldn't BOOST_ROOT be /usr/local/boost? If that works but fails for the libs (as they are not under /usr/local/boost the way you describe it), try to make a symlink /usr/local/boost/libs -> /usr/local/lib/boost

Comment: I typed in an incorrect path to the include files in the first sentence, now fixed.

Comment: autotools and make exist in versions that run on Windows using Cygwin AFAIK, but it is difficult to use those.  I think that effort spent on developing a new system like CMake that everyone would then need to learn how to use in addition to autotools would be better spent making the current tools easier to use.

Comment: The *easiest* way which worked for me is to do
set(  BOOST_ROOT      .../myPath/...  )
within the CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @jmendeth How about qmake?  It's also crossplatform (at least I've built the same program for Win, Linux and MacOS) and seems to have less magic going on than with CMake.  IMHO, qmake is easier to learn.  The downside is it's tied to Qt.

Comment: The great thing about standardized packages is that there are so many to choose from. The truth is that is used to be a breeze to compile mysql from source; now it's a multi-day nightmare.

Answer (score 47):

I was finally able to get what I wanted with

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$TARGET \
    -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=TRUE \
    -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=TRUE \
    -DBOOST_ROOT:PATHNAME=$TARGET \
    -DBoost_LIBRARY_DIRS:FILEPATH=${TARGET}/lib
```

Comment: `-DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=TRUE` nailed it for me.

Comment: Using `-DBOOST_ROOT:PATHNAME` was sufficient for me.

Comment: What is `$TARGET`?

Answer (score 31):

### The short version

You only need `BOOST_ROOT`, but you're going to want to disable searching the system for your local Boost if you have multiple installations or cross-compiling for iOS or Android. In which case add `Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS` is set to false.

```
set( BOOST_ROOT "" CACHE PATH "Boost library path" )
set( Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS on CACHE BOOL "Do not search system for Boost" )
```

Normally this is passed on the CMake command-line using the syntax `-D<VAR>=value`.

### The longer version

Officially speaking the [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html) page states these variables should be used to 'hint' the location of Boost.

> This module reads hints about search locations from variables:

```
BOOST_ROOT             - Preferred installation prefix
 (or BOOSTROOT)
BOOST_INCLUDEDIR       - Preferred include directory e.g. <prefix>/include
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR       - Preferred library directory e.g. <prefix>/lib
Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS  - Set to ON to disable searching in locations not
                         specified by these hint variables. Default is OFF.
Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS
                       - List of Boost versions not known to this module
                         (Boost install locations may contain the version)
```

This makes a theoretically correct incantation:

```
cmake -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=TRUE \
      -DBOOST_ROOT=/path/to/boost-dir
```

#### When you compile from source

```
include( ExternalProject )

set( boost_URL "http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.63.0/boost_1_63_0.tar.bz2" )
set( boost_SHA1 "9f1dd4fa364a3e3156a77dc17aa562ef06404ff6" )
set( boost_INSTALL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/third_party/boost )
set( boost_INCLUDE_DIR ${boost_INSTALL}/include )
set( boost_LIB_DIR ${boost_INSTALL}/lib )

ExternalProject_Add( boost
        PREFIX boost
        URL ${boost_URL}
        URL_HASH SHA1=${boost_SHA1}
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND
        ./bootstrap.sh
        --with-libraries=filesystem
        --with-libraries=system
        --with-libraries=date_time
        --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
        BUILD_COMMAND
        ./b2 install link=static variant=release threading=multi runtime-link=static
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
        INSTALL_DIR ${boost_INSTALL} )

set( Boost_LIBRARIES
        ${boost_LIB_DIR}/libboost_filesystem.a
        ${boost_LIB_DIR}/libboost_system.a
        ${boost_LIB_DIR}/libboost_date_time.a )
message( STATUS "Boost static libs: " ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

Then when you call this script you'll need to include the boost.cmake script (mine is in the a subdirectory), include the headers, indicate the dependency, and link the libraries.

```
include( boost )
include_directories( ${boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )
add_dependencies( MyProject boost )
target_link_libraries( MyProject
                       ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

Answer (score 21):

I had a similar issue, CMake finding a vendor-installed Boost only, but my cluster had a locally installed version which is what *I* wanted it to use. Red Hat Linux 6.

Anyway, it looks like all the `BOOSTROOT`, `BOOST_ROOT`, and `Boost_DIR` stuff would get annoyed unless one also sets `Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE` (e.g add to cmd line `-DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=TRUE`).

(I will concede the usefulness of CMake for multiplatform, but I can still hate it.)

Comment: CMake itself is not so bad at all, and getting better with time. But the findBoost and findPython modules are clearly written by the guy who hates the world.

Comment: it was necessary for me too (Ubuntu Linux)

Answer (score 16):

Generally the most common mistake is *not cleaning your build directory* after adding new options. I have Boost installed from system packet manager. Its version is 1.49.

I also downloaded Boost 1.53 and "installed" it under `$HOME/installs`.

The only thing that I had to do in my project was to (I keep sources in `my_project_directory/src`):

```
cd my_project_directory
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/installs/include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/installs/lib ../src
```

And that's it. Ta bum tss.

But if I'd make after `cd build` -> `cmake ../src` it would set Boost from the system path. Then doing `cmake -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/installs/include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/installs/lib ../src` would change nothing.

*You have to clean your build directory* ( `cd build && rm -rf *` ;) )

Comment: When I try that I get "Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:     CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH     CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH"

Comment: What version of boost and cmake?

Comment: CMake 3.2.2 and Boost 1.55

Comment: Do not use the variables I mentioned. It should be sufficient to use BOOST_ROOT/BOOST_INCLUDEDIR/BOOST_LIBRARYDIR with Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS set to ON.

Comment: When I do -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=ON -DBOOST_ROOT=/home/doriad/bin/boost_1.55.0/ in a fresh build directory, I get compiler errors showing that /usr/include/boost headers are still being used.

Comment: Ah, sorry, find_package was returning BOOST_ROOT=FALSE because I was searching for a header-only library of boost.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue, and I could use customized Boost libraries by adding the below lines to my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS TRUE)
if (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS)
  set(BOOST_ROOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../3p/boost")
  set(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS "${BOOST_ROOT}/include")
  set(BOOST_LIBRARY_DIRS "${BOOST_ROOT}/lib")
endif (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED regex date_time system filesystem thread graph program_options)
include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: Hi, I followed your tips, and I got an error `Could not find module FindBOOST.cmake or a configuration file for package BOOST.` How to handle it ?

Comment: @just_rookie I think you can fix this issue by having a local cmake then use it to compile both customized Boost libraries and your code.

Answer (score 12):

There is a generic method to give CMake directions about where to find libraries.

When looking for a library, CMake looks first in the following variables:

- `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for libraries
- `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` and `INCLUDE_PATH` for includes

If you declare your Boost files in one of the environment variables, CMake will find it. Example:

```
export CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="/stuff/lib.boost.1.52/lib:$CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH"
export CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="/stuff/lib.boost.1.52/include:$CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH"
```

If it's too cumbersome, you can also use a nice installing tool I wrote that will do everything for you: [C++ version manager](https://github.com/Offirmo/cvm)

Answer (score 3):

Try this flag: `-DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=TRUE`. After hours of trying and fixing, only adding this flag worked for me.

What I ran was:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=TRUE
```

Comment: This helped me, I succeed by using `cmake -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=TRUE -DBOOST_ROOT=/work/boost_1_75_0 ..`

Answer (score 2):

I spent most of my evening trying to get this working. I tried all of the -DBOOST_* &c. directives with CMake, but it kept linking to my system Boost libraries, even after clearing and re-configuring my build area repeatedly.

At the end I modified the generated Makefile and voided the cmake_check_build_system target to do nothing (like 'echo ""') so that it wouldn't overwrite my changes when I ran make, and then did 'grep -rl "lboost_python" * | xargs sed -i "s:-lboost_python:-L/opt/sw/gcc5/usr/lib/ -lboost_python:g' in my build/ directory to explicitly point all the build commands to the Boost installation I wanted to use. Finally, that worked.

I acknowledge that it is an **ugly** kludge, but I am just putting it out here for the benefit of those who come up against the same brick wall, and just want to work around it and get work done.

Answer (score 2):

In CMake, you can add the following to your `CMakelists`:

```
# install boost by apt-get method
include_directories(BEFORE SYSTEM "/usr/include") 

#  or install by building from src
# include_directories(BEFORE SYSTEM "/usr/local/include")
```

This method saved my serveral months. you can try it.
By the way, as a temporary solution, you can rename directories you don't expect to find as below:

```sh
sudo mv /usr/local/include/boost /usr/local/include/boost_bak
```

Hopefully, it will help people who are in deep trouble like me.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem, but trying the hints here didn't help, unfortunately.

The only thing that helped was to download the newest version from the Boost page, compile and install it as
described in *[Installing Boost 1.50 on Ubuntu 12.10](http://piyushparkash.blogspot.de/2012/10/installing-boost-150-in-ubuntu-1210.html)*.

In my case I worked with Boost 1.53.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem on a Linux server, where two versions of Boost have been installed. One is the precompiled 1.53.0 version which counts as old in 2018; it's in `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib64`. The version I want to use is 1.67.0, as a minimum version of 1.65.1 is required for another C++ library I'm installing; it's in `/opt/boost`, which has `include` and `lib` subdirectories. As suggested in previous answers, I set variables in `CMakeLists.txt` to specify where to look for Boost 1.67.0 as follows

```
include_directories(/opt/boost/include/)
include_directories(/opt/boost/lib/)
set(BOOST_ROOT /opt/boost/)
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /opt/boost/include/)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /opt/boost/lib)
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS TRUE)
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE TRUE)
```

But CMake doesn't honor those changes. Then I found an article online: *[CMake can use a local Boost](https://scaron.info/blog/cmake-can-use-a-local-boost.html)*, and realized that I need to change the variables in `CMakeCache.txt`. There I found that the Boost-related variables are still pointing to the default Boost 1.53.0, so no wonder CMake doesn't honor my changes in `CMakeLists.txt`. Then I set the Boost-related variables in `CMakeCache.txt`

```
Boost_DIR:PATH=Boost_DIR-NOTFOUND
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/opt/boost/include/
Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG:PATH=/opt/boost/lib
Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE:PATH=/opt/boost/lib
```

I also changed the variables pointing to the non-header, compiled parts of the Boost library to point to the version I want. Then CMake successfully built the library that depends on a recent version of Boost.

Answer (score 0):

While configure could find my Boost installation, CMake could not.

Locate FindBoost.cmake and look for LIBRARY_HINTS to see what sub-packages it is looking for. In my case it wanted the MPI and graph libraries.

```
 # Compute component-specific hints.
  set(_Boost_FIND_LIBRARY_HINTS_FOR_COMPONENT "")
  if(${COMPONENT} STREQUAL "mpi" OR ${COMPONENT} STREQUAL "mpi_python" OR
     ${COMPONENT} STREQUAL "graph_parallel")
    foreach(lib ${MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES} ${MPI_C_LIBRARIES})
      if(IS_ABSOLUTE "${lib}")
        get_filename_component(libdir "${lib}" PATH)
        string(REPLACE "\\" "/" libdir "${libdir}")
        list(APPEND _Boost_FIND_LIBRARY_HINTS_FOR_COMPONENT ${libdir})
      endif()
    endforeach()
  endif()
```

apt-cache search ... I installed the dev packages since I was building code, and the dev package drags in all the dependencies. I'm not so sure that a standard Boost install needs Open MPI, but this is OK for now.

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-mpi-dev libboost-mpi-python-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-graph-parallel-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added the environment variable Boost_INCLUDE_DIR or add it to the cmake command -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR and point to the include folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
My approach was to define which version to use (if any) via an environment variable:

```
# Use speficic version if BOOST_VER environment variable is defined
if(NOT "$ENV{BOOST_VER}" STREQUAL "")
    find_package (Boost "$ENV{BOOST_VER}" EXACT COMPONENTS system unit_test_framework log log_setup filesystem thread REQUIRED)
else()
    # Use default version
    find_package (Boost COMPONENTS system unit_test_framework log log_setup filesystem thread REQUIRED)
endif()
```