# CMake find_package() Eclipse, OS X

Tags: cmake, libraries

I managed to create `Make Target` in Eclipse and add a CMakeListst.txt to a very simple project and it worked.

Now, my next step is to use two external libraries, Boost and Eigen.

My project is in `/Users/MyUser/Documents/workspace/Test`
The libraries are `/Users/MyUser/Documents/MyLib/Libraries`

Now, in the `CMakeLists.txt` file I try to find Boost and Eigen, which are in the libraries folder, but always the returned message is

> CMake Error at CMake/TPLs/FindBoost.cmake:1126 (message):   Unable to
>   find the requested Boost libraries.
>
> Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the
>   root   directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory
>   containing   Boost's headers. Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   CMakeLists.txt:23 (FIND_PACKAGE)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! CMake Error at /Applications/CMake
>   2.8-11.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108
>   (message):   Could NOT find Eigen3 (missing: EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS
>   EIGEN3_VERSION_OK)   (Required is at least version "2.91.0") Call
>   Stack (most recent call first):   /Applications/CMake
>   2.8-11.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315
>   (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)   CMake/TPLs/FindEigen3.cmake:76
>   (find_package_handle_standard_args)   CMakeLists.txt:30 (FIND_PACKAGE)

I am new to CMake, so I must be missing some way to tell CMake to search in my library folder. How can I find the packages with CMake when building the project?

BTW I'm working under Mac OS X Mavericks.

**EDIT**

Reading through the file `FindEigen3.cmake` there should be a variable called `EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS` that points to the include directory of Eigen, is this true?

Now, from the following message

`Could NOT find Eigen3 (missing: EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS EIGEN3_VERSION_OK)`

I would think that cmake is actually finding that directory as it says **EIGEN3_VERSION_OK** but then why can't cmake find the rest of the include files?

Am I still missing something? I created the environment variable within Eclipse and then add a line to the `FindEigen3.cmake` to test the value of the environment variable `EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS`

`message(STATUS "Eigen version: ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}")`

But the message I'm getting is

`--Eigen version: EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS-NOTFOUND`

Any advise?

**EDIT**

I tried with the question-related answers but none was able to make Eclipse+CMake find Boost and Eigen libraries. I guess the problem here is how to make Eclipse recognize the system variables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get cmake to find my boost installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016448/how-can-i-get-cmake-to-find-my-boost-installation)

Comment: Thanks @Peter but the problem there is related to the unix system, here my problem is making Elicpse work together with CMake. I tried some of the stuff there but CMake in Eclipse still sends the same message error

Comment: Do you use CMakeBuilder plugin?

Comment: @Peter nope, I downloaded directly from CMake's website and installed on my Mac. Then, followed [this](http://www.voom.net/use-cmake-with-eclipse). However, I "installed" Boost and Eigen in an arbitrary path which I don't know how to make CMake look for that path I chose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do not believe in setting environment variables in Eclipse, you can pass Cmake-defines either directly to cmake command:

```
cmake -E chdir Release/ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ... -DBOOST_ROOT:PATHNAME=boost/install/dir ...
```

or define them in your CMakeLists.txt before find boost/eigen3

```
SET(BOOST_ROOT boost/install/dir)
...
FIND_PACKAGE(BOOST ... )
```

or use environment variables within your OS/shell. You must define them **before** launching the Eclipse. E.g. from bash, do

```
export BOOST_ROOT=boost/install/dir
eclipse
```

Note that you have to define all variables needed for both boost and eigen3. You can place some [debugging messages](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3amessage) in your CMakeLists.txt to confirm that you pass them correctly:

```
MESSAGE("Boost root: ${BOOST_ROOT}")
```

Comment: I tried using the debugging messages with `MESSAGE("Boost root: ${PATH}")` but when execute the Make Target in Eclipse my path variable is not recognized. What could be the problem?

Comment: If you want to see your environment variable, do `MESSAGE("Path: $ENV{PATH}")`

Comment: It worked setting the environment variables within the `CMakeLists.txt` file. Nevertheless, why aren't they recognized when declared in Eclipse?

Comment: In Eclipse you declare environment variables ($ENV{something}), but by SET you define cmake variables (${something}). FindModules may use cmake variables or enviroment variables, depends what author of the FindModules wanted.