# cmake find_package specify path

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, linker, shared-libraries

I have 2 versions of OpenCV installed on my machine. One is in `/usr/local/opencv3.1`. I presume the install location of the other one (version 3.4) is `/usr/local`. Anyway, `find_package(OpenCV 3.0 REQUIRED)` sets `OpenCV_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/share/OpenCV`. This folder contains:

```
haarcascades  OpenCVConfig.cmake          OpenCVModules-release.cmake
java          OpenCVConfig-version.cmake  valgrind_3rdparty.supp
lbpcascades   OpenCVModules.cmake         valgrind.supp
```

In this case, version 3.4 is used. How can I specify in CMakeLists.txt to use the other version (3.1) knowing its install location? I've tried:

```
find_package(OpenCV 3.0 REQUIRED PATH /usr/local/opencv3.1)
```

Which returns an error:

```
Could NOT find OpenCV (missing: PATH /usr/local/opencv3.1) (found suitable version "3.4.1", minimum required is "3.0")
```

and

```
set(OpenCV_DIR /usr/local/opencv3.1/OpenCV/*) # also tried OpenCV_ROOT_DIR, OPENCV_ROOT_DIR
find_package(OpenCV 3.0 REQUIRED)
```

Which does nothing. It still finds version 3.4. I'd be grateful for any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In the [find_package documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) you have that you can set a path to be searched with `PATHS` you were missing the S... also you can do something like:

```
find_package (<package> PATHS paths... NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_package (<package>)
```

Which will check for the path you wrote first, the if it is found it will set found to true and the second instruction will be skipped.

Also, you can use the `EXACT` option to match an specific version, in case it tries to select 3.4 due to being a newer version.

```
find_package(OpenCV 3.1 EXACT REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local/opencv3.1)
```

I hope this helps, if not, write a comment

Comment: find_package(OpenCV 3.1 EXACT REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local/opencv3.1) works in my case. Thank you.

Comment: I just tested this, and still didn't work, until I commented the second line (i.e., only worked when there was JUST the option with the specified path)

Comment: @Bersan The documentation says to use it multiple times... Normally I only use the first one but without `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` when I need one library in a specific path and usually it works good.... However I used it for libraries that are not installed in my system but just compiled....

Comment: it works for me, if I set ```set(SDL2_DIR /usr/local/lib/cmake/SDL2)``` before find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

Comment: Also works for OpenCV 4.4 which is installed in /usr/local/ (default installed from source)
My command:
find_package(OpenCV 4.4 EXACT REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local/)
Thanks!!!