# How can I install Libigl lab on Windows Os?

Tags: c++, c, 3d, libigl

Can some one example me step by step how to install this lab? I`m using tutorial from the libigl website and I dont really understand what to do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This website relates to programming problems, it is not a support to install programs and your question is thus quite off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Did you seen [example project page](https://libigl.github.io/#libigl-example-project) (and especially [GitHub of it](https://github.com/libigl/libigl-example-project))? It is well exaplained.

```
# Installing 
git clone https://github.com/libigl/libigl.git
cd libigl/
git submodule update --init --recursive
cd ..

# Downloading example project
git clone https://github.com/libigl/libigl-example-project.git
cd libigl-example-project/

# Building the project
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

<sup>Taken from GitHub page of example project.</sup>

If you occur problem CMake could found the library, I suggest to point the library in example project CMakeLists (here is [related StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816206/cmake-find-package-specify-path)).