# In CMake, can I use an installed target in the build tree?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to cross compile to an ARM target, which already has a fakeroot directory with OpenCV installed.
When using `find_package(OpenCV)`, it manages to find the OpenCV directory (after setting `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` to the fakeroot directory), but then it says:

```
CMake Error at /fakeroot/usr/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVModules.cmake:379 (message):
  The imported target "opencv_core" references the file

     "/usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.1.0"
```

Can I add a prefix to point to the correct location of the file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are a few questions about this topic already on Stack Overflow! Have you seen and tried what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8714718/3987854) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49816516/3987854)? Does your fakeroot OpenCV installation contain a `OpenCVConfig.cmake` or `OpenCV-config.cmake` file?

Comment: Thanks you for the reply.
The threads you referenced are discussing a different problem. In my case CMake manages to find the package, as my fakeroot contains `OpenCVConfig.cmake`, but this file references to libraries and include directories which are relative to the fakeroot (e.g. `/usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.1.0`, which in my case is `/fakeroot//usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.1.0`).