# CMake: how to get PATHS variable for find_package?

Tags: linux, cmake, build, harfbuzz

Here is an example how to specify `PATHS` variable to make cmake be able to find library:
[cmake find_package specify path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816206/cmake-find-package-specify-path)
But how to get this `PATHS` variable for specific library?

For example I have installed `apt-get install libharfbuzz-dev` and `dpkg -L libharfbuzz-dev` shows me:

```
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/harfbuzz
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-blob.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-buffer.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-common.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-deprecated.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-face.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-font.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-ft.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-glib.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-gobject-enums.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-gobject-structs.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-gobject.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-graphite2.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-icu.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-ot-font.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-ot-layout.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-ot-math.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-ot-shape.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-ot-tag.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-ot-var.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-ot.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-set.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-shape-plan.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-shape.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-unicode.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-version.h
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz-gobject.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz-icu.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/harfbuzz-gobject.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/harfbuzz-icu.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/harfbuzz.pc
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libharfbuzz-dev
/usr/share/doc/libharfbuzz-dev/copyright
/usr/share/gir-1.0
/usr/share/gir-1.0/HarfBuzz-0.0.gir
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz-gobject.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz-icu.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so
/usr/share/doc/libharfbuzz-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
```

Which path should I use?

**Update:**

Error message:

```
CMake Error at <some_path>/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindHarfbuzz.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Harfbuzz",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Harfbuzz" with any
  of the following names:

    HarfbuzzConfig.cmake
    harfbuzz-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Harfbuzz" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Harfbuzz_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Harfbuzz" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

I tried to add path via `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` like `cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` but it doesn't help.

Comment: The libraries are located here: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, so it looks like you should use that path. I'm confused if there is another question here? If the library isn't located in the *standard* system paths, and the `PATHS` arguments is needed, then the hard-coded path may differ for every library...

Comment: @squareskittles Is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` standard library path? Is there any reason why cmake can't find it by default?

Comment: Please, add **exact** error message into the question post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Updated question.

Comment: Err, have you ever read that error message? It tells about `FindHarfbuzz.cmake` script, which should be provided by your project, and about `HarfbuzzConfig.cmake` (or `harfbuzz-config.cmake`) one, which should come with the library. You have none of them, so CMake cannot find that library. You could get `FindHarfbuzz.cmake` script from somewhere. Or, since the package provides `.pc` file, you could use `pkg-config` utility ([pkg_check_modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html) CMake function) instead of `find_package`.