# Integrate thirdpary shared libraries(*.so) into multiple projects using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, yocto

I have the following layout which contains multiple projects separate directories (It's a CPP project):

```
Demo
├── Lib
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── inc
│   └── lib
│       ├── crypto_ic.so
│       └── crypto.so
├── Proj1
│   ├── App1
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
└── Proj2
    ├── App2
    └── CMakeLists.txt
```

I created one separate `third-party-lib.bb` file to install `crypto_ic.so`,`crypto.so` into `/usr/lib/` in the target using `do_install_append`.

All applications are depending on third-party libraries. There are no parent cmake for *proj1,proj2* those are independent projects built by `*.bb` files using yocto.

Now I need to integrate the *third party library* for all the applications. I created one interface library for the *third party* headers and using `find_package` I am able to find the headers and the compilation is working fine.

**CMakeLists.txt(Lib)**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(crypto VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
add_library(crypto INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(crypto INTERFACE
        Boost::boost
)
target_include_directories(crypto INTERFACE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)
# Create and Install *-config.cmake,*-version.cmake files
# Install exported targets, i.e. *-targets.cmake
# Install header files
```

**CMakeLists.txt(Proj1)**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(App1 VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

find_package(crypto REQUIRED)
add_executable(run Run.cpp)
target_link_libraries(run PUBLIC
        crypto
)
```

But the problem is while linking I am getting a linker error.

> Run.cpp: undefined reference to 'Intialize(std::string hashName)'

`Initialize` function definition is available in the shared library.

Any thoughts on how to fix the issue and how to remove the hardcode path to the library in CMake?.

I am new to CMake and not sure this is a good approach to follow, only reason I created the Interface library is to install the headers in target and find the package. I can modify it if there are some better solutions?

**Edit:**

I found the issue in the cmake, I didn't link the shared library files (`*.so`) in the application that's the reason I am getting the linker error. But I am not getting how to link that from the target?

Comment: How about just using [find_package with hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49816516/4123703) for this library? It should work but I'm not sure if it's a good practice.

Comment: I checked the example link. In my case, I need to install headers and `*.so` files are not part of the host machine rootfs it will be installed in the Image which created by yocto.

Comment: "I am getting a linker error saying .." - No, do not *describe* the error message. Instead, show it (add to the question post). Also add to the post the code which causes it. It could be that you incorrectly **use** your library, or forget to add `find_dependency(Boost)` into your `*-config.cmake` file.

Comment: updated the question with the changes.`Boost` is working fine,No issues in the `*-config.cmake`

Comment: Finally, I fixed this issue. I installed the library and its config,version Cmake using bb file.In the app I find the library using `find_library`.Its working now,