# cmake find_package specify path redux

Tags: c++, cmake, ceres-solver

I have two versions of the Ceres solver installed. One is in `/opt/local/lib` and the other is in `/usr/local/lib/` and I am using cmake to build an application that uses the latter. In my `build` subdirectory the following works fine:

```
cmake -DCeres_DIR=/usr/local/lib/cmake/Ceres/ ..
```

I would rather specify the correct path in the `CMakeLists.txt` file as [described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816206/cmake-find-package-specify-path), but the following fails:

```
find_package(Ceres PATHS /usr/local/lib/cmake/Ceres)
```

When I do this, cmake complains since it finds the wrong `CeresConfig.cmake` file which was built using a different version of Eigen:

```
CMake Error at /opt/local/lib/cmake/Ceres/CeresConfig.cmake:85 (message):
  Failed to find Ceres - Found Eigen dependency, but the version of Eigen
  found (3.4.0) does not exactly match the version of Eigen Ceres was
  compiled with (3.3.9).
  ....
```

Clearly is it using the Ceres installation in `/opt/local/lib` not `/usr/local/lib`.
Why isn't the `PATHS` specification working in this case?

Comment: Have you cleared CMake cache (`CMakeCache.txt`) before your new attempt? Also, you could add option `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` to the `find_package` call, so CMake won't search the package elsewhere except the `PATHS`.

Comment: `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` did the trick. I didn't see this documented. --thanks! Add as answer and I'll check it.

Comment: Actually, the behavior of `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` is follows: **Without** `NO_DEFAULT_PATH`, CMake firstly checks the package under `PATHS`. If CMake cannot find the package here, then it searches under some predefined locations. **With** `NO_DEFAULT_PATH`, CMake checkes the package under `PATHS`. If it cannot find the package their, then it reports an error. So, `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` simply cannot help you to find one package instead of another: it can only help you to **not find** an unwanted package. BTW, the option is documented here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't understand why it didn't first find it under `/usr/local` then -- according to the behavior you describe it should. Actually, according to the docs, looking at the `PATHS` is the ninth step!