# How set CMake to find a local package FFmpeg?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, cmake, build

I am trying write CMakeLists with FFmpeg package, with compile on Windows and Linux.
First downloaded from [FFmpeg-Builds](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases) shared releases

I imagine the structure of the project like this:

```
<project root>
deps/
  ffmpeg/
    win-x64/
      incluve/
      lib/
      bin/
    linux-x64/
      incluve/
      lib/
      bin/
src/
CMakeLists.txt
```

How to help CMake find libraries: avcodec, avformat, avutil, etc?
Maybe in the folder `lib/pkgconfig` using *PkgConfig* it is possible to specify the path.
But I dont know how

Comment: My expectation is you want to start reading here: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.23/command/find_package.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.23/command/find_package.html)

Comment: It didn't help. I still didn't understand how to specify the local path to the library

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816206/cmake-find-package-specify-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816206/cmake-find-package-specify-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked well for me on Linux with cmake.
You will have to find the equivalents for Windows.
I used ffmpeg on Windows, but without cmake (i.e. directly in a Visual Studio project).

1. Install pkg-config, nasm:

```
    sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config

    sudo apt-get install nasm
```

2. Download ffmpeg source code:

   https://ffmpeg.org/download.html
3. Build ffmpeg and install it:

   ```
   tar -xvf <downloaded_filename>
   cd /root/folder/with/ffmpeg/src
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
4. Add the following to your CMakeLists.txt:

   In the beginning:

   ```
    find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
    pkg_check_modules(LIBAV REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET
        libavdevice
        libavfilter
        libavformat
        libavcodec
        libswresample
        libswscale
        libavutil
    )

    set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})
   ```

   In the linker area:

   ```
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC PkgConfig::LIBAV)
   ```

Comment: Can I download already compiled libraries from the link in the question? Besides, I need support for compiling under Windows. Isn't it easier to use already compiled libraries?

Comment: For Linux I found it easier to build from source. For Windows I believe the pre-built libraries are easier to use. This is indeed what I did myself. But as I wrote I used them directly in the VisualStudio project (added include and library paths, and link with appropriate libs).