# Unable to use PATHS option in find_package to point to a locally installed project (not installed in the system)

Tags: cmake

I am new to CMake. I do not know many details about it. I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49816206/7571421) about using the `PATHS` option to point `find_package` to use my locally installed project in the build directory.

[image: Directory Structure]

I have installed the packages locally in the `build/third_party` directory. (I have attached the directory structure for the `protobuf` package, for example.)

In one of the CMakeLists.txt in my project, I want to direct it to use this `protobuf` package instead of the `protobuf` in the system's default path.

```
#a snippet of the CMakeLists.txt
message("========================>FROM SERVERLESS<======================")

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(svgpu-manager C CXX)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH)

set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE TRUE)
# find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED PATHS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/third_party/") #### line 11
# find_package(OpenCV 3.1 EXACT REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local/opencv3.1)
message(STATUS "Using protobuf ${Protobuf_VERSION}")
set(_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF protobuf::libprotobuf)
set(_REFLECTION gRPC::grpc++_reflection)

find_program(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC protoc PATHS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/third_party/")

###The CMakeLists.txt file continues...
```

When I try to `cmake`, I get the following result:

```bash
...
...
========================>FROM SERVERLESS<======================
CMake Warning at /usr/local/lib/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-config.cmake:9 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:                                                                                            
                                                                                                                               
    /usr/local/lib/cmake/absl/abslConfig.cmake                                                                                 
                                                                                                                               
  but it set absl_FOUND to FALSE so package "absl" is considered to be NOT                                                     
  FOUND.  Reason given by package:                                                                                             
                                                                                                                               
  The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing:                                                              
  protobuf::gmock                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                               
Call Stack (most recent call first):                                                                                           
  worker/serverless_gpu/CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)                                                                       
                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                               
-- Using protobuf 24.0.0
-- Using gRPC 1.59.0-dev

...
...
```

Unfortunately, `find_package` get the system default path for `protobuf` and ignores my `PATHS`. Any guidance on how to fix this issue?

Comment: The path of your protobuf installation is `third_party/protobuf/`, no a `third_party/` as you set in the PATHS. You may also pass `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` option for `find_package`, so CMake won't search a package in other directories.

Comment: ... or consider adding these paths to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.