# How to force a CMake target to use a specific OpenSSL version

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl, shared-libraries, vcpkg

I have a CMake project in Linux where I build several shared libraries and some of them need OpenSSL latest version. I use Microsoft `vcpkg` for my toolchain and I had to install `OpenSSL 3.2.0 23 Nov 2023` using `./vcpkg install openssl:x64-linux`.

One of the libraries, `myrrlib`, uses a proprietary library for which `libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a` are provided by the vendor in the library source folder. Their version appears to be `OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021` when I run `strings libcrypto.a | grep "OpenSSL"`.

In the root folder, my `CMakeLists.txt` has `find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)`, which will result in `vcpkg` finding the following file for `libcrypto.a`:

```
/root/programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libcrypto.a
```

My question is how can I force using a OpenSSL 1.1.1 for `myrrlib`?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)

set(RR_LIB_DIR "external/pakages/rr/lib")   
set(RR_LIB_FILES
        vendorlib1
        vendorlib2
        vendorlib3
        ssl    # libssl.a is provided by the RR library (it is not installed by vcpkg)
        crypto # libcrypto.a is provided by the RR library (it is not installed by vcpkg)
)

add_library(myrrlib SHARED)
set_property(TARGET myrrlib PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
target_sources(myrrlib PRIVATE "src/myrrlib.cpp" "src/myrrlib.h")
target_include_directories(myrrlib PUBLIC ${RR_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_directories(myrrlib PUBLIC ${RR_LIB_DIR})
target_link_libraries(myrrlib PUBLIC ${RR_LIB_FILES})
```

When I build the shard library `myrrlib` I get the following link errors:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/ld: warning: alignment 8 of symbol `bio_lookup_lock' in /root/programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_addr.o) is smaller than 32 in /mnt/c/Dev/myproject/external/packages/rr/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o)
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/ld: /root/programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_addr.o): in function `BIO_ADDR_new':
/root/programs/vcpkg/buildtrees/openssl/x64-linux-dbg/../src/nssl-3.2.0-5a1db6e780.clean/crypto/bio/bio_addr.c:53: multiple definition of `BIO_ADDR_new'; /mnt/c/Dev/myproject/external/packages/rr/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/ld: /root/programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_addr.o): in function `BIO_ADDR_free':
/root/programs/vcpkg/buildtrees/openssl/x64-linux-dbg/../src/nssl-3.2.0-5a1db6e780.clean/crypto/bio/bio_addr.c:64: multiple definition of `BIO_ADDR_free'; /mnt/c/Dev/myproject/external/packages/rr/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0x50): first defined here
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/ld: /root/programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_addr.o): in function `BIO_ADDR_clear':
/root/programs/vcpkg/buildtrees/openssl/x64-linux-dbg/../src/nssl-3.2.0-5a1db6e780.clean/crypto/bio/bio_addr.c:96: multiple definition of `BIO_ADDR_clear'; /mnt/c/Dev/myproject/external/packages/rr/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0x70): first defined here
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/ld: /root/programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-bio_addr.o): in function `BIO_ADDR_make':
/root/programs/vcpkg/buildtrees/openssl/x64-linux-dbg/../src/nssl-3.2.0-5a1db6e780.clean/crypto/bio/bio_addr.c:106: multiple definition of `BIO_ADDR_make'; /mnt/c/Dev/myproject/external/packages/rr/lib/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0x110): first defined here

...
many more
...

/root/programs/vcpkg/buildtrees/openssl/x64-linux-dbg/../src/nssl-3.2.0-5a1db6e780.clean/crypto/engine/eng_lib.c:280: multiple definition of `ENGINE_get_finish_function'; /mnt/c/Dev/myproject/external/packages/rr/lib/libcrypto.a(eng_lib.o):eng_lib.c:(.text+0x530): first defined here
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/ld: /root/programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-eng_lib.o): in function `ENGINE_get_ctrl_function':
/root/programs/vcpkg/buildtrees/openssl/x64-linux-dbg/../src/nssl-3.2.0-5a1db6e780.clean/crypto/engine/eng_lib.c:285: multiple definition of `ENGINE_get_ctrl_function'; /mnt/c/Dev/myproject/external/packages/rr/lib/libcrypto.a(eng_lib.o):eng_lib.c:(.text+0x540): first defined here
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/ld: /root/programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-eng_lib.o): in function `ENGINE_get_flags':
/root/programs/vcpkg/buildtrees/openssl/x64-linux-dbg/../src/nssl-3.2.0-5a1db6e780.clean/crypto/engine/eng_lib.c:290: multiple definition of `ENGINE_get_flags'; /mnt/c/Dev/myproject/external/packages/rr/lib/libcrypto.a(eng_lib.o):eng_lib.c:(.text+0x550): first defined here
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/ld: /root/programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-eng_lib.o): in function `ENGINE_get_cmd_defns':
/root/programs/vcpkg/buildtrees/openssl/x64-linux-dbg/../src/nssl-3.2.0-5a1db6e780.clean/crypto/engine/eng_lib.c:295: multiple definition of `ENGINE_get_cmd_defns'; /mnt/c/Dev/myproject/external/packages/rr/lib/libcrypto.a(eng_lib.o):eng_lib.c:(.text+0x560): first defined here
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/ld: /root/programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto-lib-eng_lib.o): in function `ENGINE_get_static_state':
/root/programs/vcpkg/buildtrees/openssl/x64-linux-dbg/../src/nssl-3.2.0-5a1db6e780.clean/crypto/engine/eng_lib.c:307: multiple definition of `ENGINE_get_static_state'; /mnt/c/Dev/myproject/external/packages/rr/lib/libcrypto.a(eng_lib.o):eng_lib.c:(.text+0x570): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/myrrlib.dir/build.make:119: lib/libmyrrlib.so] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:520: CMakeFiles/myrrlib.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:527: CMakeFiles/myrrlib.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:283: myrrlib] Error 2
```

If I build it as static, `add_library(myrrlib STATIC)`, I can successfully build the library with no issues. I don't know where the problem is when I build it as a shared library.

Could someone kindly let me know how this can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL/DR:
First of all changing to `STATIC` didn't solve the problem, but it just delayed it in time to the final linkage.
Solution is to use only one version of OpenSSL and in your case it looks like 1.1.1m provided by the vendor would be easier(I think), so use `cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/path/to/vendor/openssl` or try using `find_package (<package> PATHS paths... NO_DEFAULT_PATH)`

To understand it lets get back to the basic how compile process looks like in this case I will explain in GCC.

When we have some C++ file `a.cpp` first is to generate object file `a.o` it's just an output of each **Translation Unit**(simply saying one `*.o` file per `.cpp` file).

Next step depends on what we want to create:

- **Static Library** (in CMake `add_library(X STATIC)`)
- **Shared Library** also called Dynamic Library (in CMake `add_library(X SHARED)`)
- **Executable** (in CMake `add_executable(X)`)

**Shared Library** and **Executable** are almost the same (**Executable** needs to have `main()`) but **Static Library** is much different because especially in this case it's not linking everything and not verifying all the connections between function. So this in your case using **Static Library** not showing that some functions are linked two because there is not linking at all. Why I said `it just delayed it in time to the final linkage`? At the end you will need to create **Executable** or **Shared Library** and errors of duplicates will reappear.

The demonstrate the issue we need 2 static libs(let say `a` and `b`) that will simulate two difference version of OpenSSL, next library that will be our `myrrlib` from the question and to show that it's only delayed in time some executable (or dynamic lib as in this case they behave the same).

Let create a.hpp

```
#pragma once

int add(int, int);
int mul(int, int);
```

a.cpp

```cpp
#include "a.hpp"

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int mul(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

b.hpp

```
#pragma once

int add(int, int);
int sub(int, int);
```

b.cpp

```cpp
#include "a.hpp"

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int sub(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}
```

also myrrlib.cpp

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"

void func()
{
  // some usage of all functions
  printf("add %i!\n", add(2, 5));
  printf("sub %i!\n", sub(2, 5));
  printf("mul %i!\n", mul(2, 5));
}
```

and main.cpp

```cpp
extern void func();

int main()
{
  func();
}
```

and CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(issue)

add_library(a STATIC a.cpp)
add_library(b STATIC b.cpp)

add_library(myrrlib STATIC myrrlib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myrrlib b a)
```

To me able to reproduce this error we need library `a` and `b` to have at least  one function in common and also one unique per library, so `add` is duplicated but `mul` and `sub` unique per lib(same happen in the example some function are the same in both versions of OpenSSL and some have to differ).

Let build it with

```bash
cmake -S . -B build
cmake --build build --clean-first
```

You should see no issues and `[100%] Built target myrrlib` but when we change `myrrlib` to `SHARED` we will get exactly the same error for `add` function.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/13.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: liba.a(a.cpp.o): in function `add(int, int)':
a.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `add(int, int)'; libb.a(b.cpp.o):b.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/myrrlib.dir/build.make:99: libmyrrlib.so] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:140: CMakeFiles/myrrlib.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

To show that error it is only delayed in time, let change it back to `STATIC` and add executable

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(issue)

add_library(a STATIC a.cpp)
add_library(b STATIC b.cpp)

add_library(myrrlib STATIC myrrlib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myrrlib b a)

add_executable(final main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(final myrrlib)
```

When we compile it we will get

```
[ 75%] Built target myrrlib
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/final.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable final
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/13.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: liba.a(a.cpp.o): in function `add(int, int)':
a.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `add(int, int)'; libb.a(b.cpp.o):b.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/final.dir/build.make:100: final] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:170: CMakeFiles/final.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

`myrrlib` compiled without errors but everything failed when creating `final` executable.

Finally to answer you questions
`My question is how can I force using a OpenSSL 1.1.1 for myrrlib?`
You have to use only one version of OpenSSL and probably provided by the vendor would be the best for you, so instead of using vcpkg to install it use `cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/path/to/vendor/openssl` or try using `find_package (<package> PATHS paths... NO_DEFAULT_PATH)`

```
If I build it as static, add_library(myrrlib STATIC),
I can successfully build the library with no issues.
I don't know where the problem is when I build it as a shared library.
```

As describe issue is not resolved but just delayed in time

Answer (score 1):

Check value of ${RR_LIB_FILES}.
Errors say that this line `target_link_libraries(myrrlib PUBLIC ${RR_LIB_FILES})` links against two libcrypto.a libraries. This is ofcourse illegal.
Print it out and check for duplicates.

I suspect that with switch from SHARED to STATIC for myrrlib also dependencies are built and/or imported (linked) as STATIC, which results (likely) with keeping libcrypto.a internally to sub-library.

Answer (score 0):

Just meet similar problem no long before. I suggest reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816206/cmake-find-package-specify-path), which I found helpful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).