# How to Prioritize Boost Include for a Specific Version on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, boost, include

The GitHub project, https://github.com/bluzelle/swarmDB , that I am working on provides an option that installs Boost 1.70.0 in the build folder and links from there.

Unfortunately, on macOS only, if the developer has installed a previous version of boost, 1.68.0 say, manually or via brew, the include and lib files are placed in

/usr/local

which causes the compiler to ignore the boost in the build folder, as it sees the older version of boost first. Since we are using new functionality in boost 1.70.0 this results in difficult to diagnose linker errors (well, not now, we know what the problem is).

The fix is to request developers remove the older version of boost, a better fix would be to ignore the older boost include folders and libraries.

How do we get the macOS c++ compilers to ignore the older boost versions include folder and libraries in favour of those installed in the build folder?

Comment: This might be a dup, here is an older question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016448/how-can-i-get-cmake-to-find-my-alternative-boost-installation

Comment: This sounds like a bug in SwarmDB. They need to make sure their include order is correct, and they didn't.