# Undefined reference error while building Boost with CMake and Clion on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, cmake, clion

(undefinierter Verweis is german and means undifined Reference)

Hi, i am using CLion with CMake 3.14, Ubuntu, BOoost 1.72.0 default compiler gcc/g++

I got this error (after deleting CMakeCache.txt):

I installed boost with

sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

AND/OR with

./bootstap.sh 
./b2 install --prefix="/home/sebastian/boost_1_72_0"

this is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(Sceduling)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread")


set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED)

add_executable(Sceduling main.cpp account.cpp bank_t.cpp alternation.cpp transaction.c)
target_link_libraries(Sceduling PRIVATE Boost::filesystem)
```

this is the result:

```
====================[ Clean | Debug ]===========================================
/opt/clion-2019.1.4/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/sebastian/Schreibtisch/git/ba-sebastian-dietl/Code/Bank_TM_Sceduling/cmake-build-debug --target clean -- -j 3
CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory /home/sebastian/Schreibtisch/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory /home/sebastian/Schreibtisch/git/ba-sebastian-dietl/Code/Bank_TM_Sceduling/cmake-build-debug where CMakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt

Clean finished

====================[ Build | all | Debug ]=====================================
/opt/clion-2019.1.4/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/sebastian/Schreibtisch/git/ba-sebastian-dietl/Code/Bank_TM_Sceduling/cmake-build-debug --target all -- -j 3
CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory /home/sebastian/Schreibtisch/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory /home/sebastian/Schreibtisch/git/ba-sebastian-dietl/Code/Bank_TM_Sceduling/cmake-build-debug where CMakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning at /opt/clion-2019.1.4/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:905 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/clion-2019.1.4/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1027 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /opt/clion-2019.1.4/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1709 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)


-- Boost version: 1.72.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/sebastian/Schreibtisch/git/ba-sebastian-dietl/Code/Bank_TM_Sceduling/cmake-build-debug
Scanning dependencies of target Sceduling
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/bank_t.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/account.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/alternation.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building C object CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/transaction.c.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Sceduling
CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/main.cpp.o: In Funktion »boost::context::fiber::~fiber()«:
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7context5fiberD2Ev[_ZN5boost7context5fiberD5Ev]+0x5b): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »ontop_fcontext«
CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/main.cpp.o: In Funktion »boost::context::fiber::resume() &&«:
main.cpp:(.text._ZNO5boost7context5fiber6resumeEv[_ZNO5boost7context5fiber6resumeEv]+0x6e): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »jump_fcontext«
CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/main.cpp.o: In Funktion »boost::fibers::context::context(unsigned long, boost::fibers::type, boost::fibers::launch)«:
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6fibers7contextC2EmNS0_4typeENS0_6launchE[_ZN5boost6fibers7contextC5EmNS0_4typeENS0_6launchE]+0x1a): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »vtable for boost::fibers::context«
CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/main.cpp.o: In Funktion »boost::fibers::fiber::fiber<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>, , void, void, void>(boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>&&)«:
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6fibers5fiberC2INS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENS3_5list0EEEJEvvvEEOT_DpT0_[_ZN5boost6fibers5fiberC5INS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENS3_5list0EEEJEvvvEEOT_DpT0_]+0x21): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »boost::context::stack_traits::default_size()«
CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/main.cpp.o: In Funktion »boost::fibers::fiber::fiber<boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>>(boost::fibers::launch, std::allocator_arg_t, boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>&&, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>&&)«:
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6fibers5fiberC2INS_7context21basic_fixedsize_stackINS3_12stack_traitsEEENS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENS7_5list0EEEJEEENS0_6launchESt15allocator_arg_tOT_OT0_DpT1_[_ZN5boost6fibers5fiberC5INS_7context21basic_fixedsize_stackINS3_12stack_traitsEEENS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENS7_5list0EEEJEEENS0_6launchESt15allocator_arg_tOT_OT0_DpT1_]+0x5f): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »boost::fibers::fiber::start_()«
CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/main.cpp.o: In Funktion »boost::fibers::worker_context<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>>::worker_context<boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits> >(boost::fibers::launch, boost::context::preallocated const&, boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>&&, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>&&)«:
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENS2_5list0EEEJEEC2INS_7context21basic_fixedsize_stackINSA_12stack_traitsEEEEENS0_6launchERKNSA_12preallocatedEOT_OS7_[_ZN5boost6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENS2_5list0EEEJEEC5INS_7context21basic_fixedsize_stackINSA_12stack_traitsEEEEENS0_6launchERKNSA_12preallocatedEOT_OS7_]+0x12f): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »boost::fibers::context::~context()«
CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/main.cpp.o: In Funktion »boost::fibers::worker_context<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>>::run_(boost::context::fiber&&)«:
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENS2_5list0EEEJEE4run_EONS_7context5fiberE[_ZN5boost6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENS2_5list0EEEJEE4run_EONS_7context5fiberE]+0x94): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »boost::fibers::context::terminate()«
CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/main.cpp.o: In Funktion »void* boost::context::detail::create_fiber2<boost::context::detail::fiber_record<boost::context::fiber, boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>, std::_Bind<boost::context::fiber (boost::fibers::worker_context<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>>::*(boost::fibers::worker_context<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>>*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(boost::context::fiber&&)> >, boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>, std::_Bind<boost::context::fiber (boost::fibers::worker_context<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>>::*(boost::fibers::worker_context<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>>*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(boost::context::fiber&&)> >(boost::context::preallocated, boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>&&, std::_Bind<boost::context::fiber (boost::fibers::worker_context<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>>::*(boost::fibers::worker_context<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>>*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(boost::context::fiber&&)>&&)«:
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7context6detail13create_fiber2INS1_12fiber_recordINS0_5fiberENS0_21basic_fixedsize_stackINS0_12stack_traitsEEESt5_BindIFMNS_6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENSB_5list0EEEJEEEFS4_OS4_EPSH_St12_PlaceholderILi1EEEEEES7_SP_EEPvNS0_12preallocatedEOT0_OT1_[_ZN5boost7context6detail13create_fiber2INS1_12fiber_recordINS0_5fiberENS0_21basic_fixedsize_stackINS0_12stack_traitsEEESt5_BindIFMNS_6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENSB_5list0EEEJEEEFS4_OS4_EPSH_St12_PlaceholderILi1EEEEEES7_SP_EEPvNS0_12preallocatedEOT0_OT1_]+0xea): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »make_fcontext«
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7context6detail13create_fiber2INS1_12fiber_recordINS0_5fiberENS0_21basic_fixedsize_stackINS0_12stack_traitsEEESt5_BindIFMNS_6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENSB_5list0EEEJEEEFS4_OS4_EPSH_St12_PlaceholderILi1EEEEEES7_SP_EEPvNS0_12preallocatedEOT0_OT1_[_ZN5boost7context6detail13create_fiber2INS1_12fiber_recordINS0_5fiberENS0_21basic_fixedsize_stackINS0_12stack_traitsEEESt5_BindIFMNS_6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENSB_5list0EEEJEEEFS4_OS4_EPSH_St12_PlaceholderILi1EEEEEES7_SP_EEPvNS0_12preallocatedEOT0_OT1_]+0x127): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »jump_fcontext«
CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/main.cpp.o: In Funktion »void boost::context::detail::fiber_entry<boost::context::detail::fiber_record<boost::context::fiber, boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>, std::_Bind<boost::context::fiber (boost::fibers::worker_context<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>>::*(boost::fibers::worker_context<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>>*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(boost::context::fiber&&)> > >(boost::context::detail::transfer_t)«:
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7context6detail11fiber_entryINS1_12fiber_recordINS0_5fiberENS0_21basic_fixedsize_stackINS0_12stack_traitsEEESt5_BindIFMNS_6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENSB_5list0EEEJEEEFS4_OS4_EPSH_St12_PlaceholderILi1EEEEEEEEvNS1_10transfer_tE[_ZN5boost7context6detail11fiber_entryINS1_12fiber_recordINS0_5fiberENS0_21basic_fixedsize_stackINS0_12stack_traitsEEESt5_BindIFMNS_6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENSB_5list0EEEJEEEFS4_OS4_EPSH_St12_PlaceholderILi1EEEEEEEEvNS1_10transfer_tE]+0x7c): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »jump_fcontext«
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7context6detail11fiber_entryINS1_12fiber_recordINS0_5fiberENS0_21basic_fixedsize_stackINS0_12stack_traitsEEESt5_BindIFMNS_6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENSB_5list0EEEJEEEFS4_OS4_EPSH_St12_PlaceholderILi1EEEEEEEEvNS1_10transfer_tE[_ZN5boost7context6detail11fiber_entryINS1_12fiber_recordINS0_5fiberENS0_21basic_fixedsize_stackINS0_12stack_traitsEEESt5_BindIFMNS_6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENSB_5list0EEEJEEEFS4_OS4_EPSH_St12_PlaceholderILi1EEEEEEEEvNS1_10transfer_tE]+0xdd): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »ontop_fcontext«
CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/main.cpp.o: In Funktion »boost::fibers::worker_context<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>>::~worker_context()«:
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENS2_5list0EEEJEED2Ev[_ZN5boost6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENS2_5list0EEEJEED5Ev]+0x22): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »boost::fibers::context::~context()«
CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN5boost6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENS2_5list0EEEJEEE[_ZTIN5boost6fibers14worker_contextINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvvENS2_5list0EEEJEEE]+0x10): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »typeinfo for boost::fibers::context«
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/build.make:144: recipe for target 'Sceduling' failed
make[2]: *** [Sceduling] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Update: Build worked, if i don't use fiber the programm finishes with Exit Code 0. If i use Fiber i get Process finished with exit code 135 (interrupted by signal 7: SIGEMT)

this is my Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fiber/all.hpp>                                                                      

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

inline
void fn() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}

int main() {
    fibers::fiber f1(fn);
    f1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) If it doesn't help you solve it, please extract a [mcve] and describe in what way your case differs. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You may need to add `set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)` before your `find_package` call. Make sure you delete the `CMakeCache.txt` file in the build directory before rerunning CMake.

Comment: Add that command I mentioned to the `CMakeLists.txt` file before the `find_package(Boost ...)` call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my Question with the result

Comment: OK. now you need to add `target_link_libraries(<yourtarget> PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})` after the definition of `<yourtarget>`, i.e. after your `add_library` or `add_executable` command.

Comment: I think I can figure out what "_undefinierter_" means but it'd be easier if you switched to an English locale before compiling so the error messages came out in English.

Comment: You should use Boost's imported targets `Boost::filesystem`, instead of the old Boost variables, such as `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS`. See this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60397133/3987854).

Comment: thanks for the answers but its still not working.... i editeted the question (see UPDATE #2)

Comment: Then, please try `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem)` instead.

Comment: doesnt work... :  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies 
     AND     imported targets and CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "executable" which is not built by
  this project.

Comment: This question has become difficult to follow with all the edits. But, if your undefined references are about Boost Fiber, wouldn't you link to `Boost::fiber` also? You would need to mention this in the `COMPONENTS` for `find_package()` also...

Comment: Instead of numerous updates to your question I would recommend you to open a new question with the SIGEMT issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the Ubuntu `Boost` package, install it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Then your `CMakeLists.txt` file should look like follows:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS fiber system filesystem REQUIRED)

add_executable(Sceduling main.cpp account.cpp bank_t.cpp alternation.cpp transaction.c)
target_link_libraries(Sceduling PRIVATE Boost::headers Boost::fiber Boost::system Boost::filesystem)
```

Otherwise if you intend to build boost yourself and install it in a custom folder your `CMakeLists.txt` file should look like follows:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 1.72.0 1.72)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)
set(Boost_ROOT <mydir>)
set(Boost_INCLUDEDIR <a_directory_with_include_files>)
set(Boost_LIBRARYDIR <a_directory_with_library_files>)

find_package(Boost 1.72.0 COMPONENTS fiber system filesystem REQUIRED)

add_executable(Sceduling main.cpp account.cpp bank_t.cpp alternation.cpp transaction.c)
target_link_libraries(Sceduling PRIVATE Boost::headers Boost::fiber Boost::system Boost::filesystem)
```

Where 1.72.0 is the version of `Boost` you have previously built and installed to `<mydir>`. If the installation puts include files and libraries under seperate directories you need to reference them in the variables `Boost_INCLUDEDIR` and `Boost_LIBRARYDIR`.

- Your `CMake` (3.14) is quite old and its `FindBoost` module does not now about the recent version of `Boost` (1.72.0). That's why you may need to set the `Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS` variable.
- No need to check `Boost_FOUND` as the `REQUIRED` keyword makes `CMake` fail if `Boost` cannot be found.
- Your target is called `Sceduling` not `executable`.
- You need at least C++11 enabled for `Boost::fiber` to work.

For further explanation of the settings please refere to the [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/FindBoost.html?highlight=findboost) CMake documentation.

Comment: Thank you, this results in:

Comment: CMake Error at /opt/clion-2019.1.4/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2147 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/sebastian/Schreibtisch/git/ba-sebastian-dietl/Code/Bank_TM_Sceduling/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Comment: You compiled boost but where is your Boost installed?

Comment: Do you really need to build Boost by yourself or can you use Ubuntu's Boost package?

Comment: doesnt matter, i just need Boost::Fibers

Comment: CMake Warning at /opt/clion-2019.1.4/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:905 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/clion-2019.1.4/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1027 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /opt/clion-2019.1.4/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1709 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)

Comment: -- Boost version: 1.72.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/sebastian/Schreibtisch/git/ba-sebastian-dietl/Code/Bank_TM_Sceduling/cmake-build-debug

Comment: These are warnings (see my note in the answer about CMake 3.14 version being too old for Boost 1.72.0). The configuration step was successful now. Does your project compile and link?

Comment: Linking fails, i get about 10 undifined reference errors: CMakeFiles/Sceduling.dir/main.cpp.o: In Funktion »boost::context::fiber::~fiber()«:
/usr/local/include/boost/context/fiber_fcontext.hpp:254: Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »ontop_fcontext« ......... undefinierter Verweis means undifined reference

Comment: my CMakeCache reads: 

//The directory containing a CMake configuration file for Boost.
Boost_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.72.0

//Boost filesystem library (debug)
Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.a

//Boost filesystem library (release)
Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.a

//Path to a file.
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/include

Comment: can you remove the CMakeCache.txt and reconfigure the project? There are both versions of Boost referenced now. The system provided one and your previously built one.

Comment: I deleted CMakeCache. i updated my question to show you the result (see UPDATE 3). thank you for suppurt!

Comment: redifned the question completly thank you for your time!

Comment: Added the missing statements for Boost::fiber to the solution.

Comment: Thank you, the first sultion worked to get no errors during build. The build finishes now. But i get SIGEMT now if i create a fiber object (see edited Question).