# Crosscompilation use boost from mounted directory

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, cmake, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a ROS package for a **Jetson nano** (`aarch64`) using my `x86_64` PC. I am using the [toolchain provided by nvidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/downloads#?search=tool%20chain&tx=$product,jetson_tx2,jetson_nano) (GCC Tool Chain for 64-bit BSP). I have been following [this article](https://medium.com/@tahsincankose/cross-compiling-ros-project-for-arm-263642b405ac) for guidance

As the compiler needs boost binaries from the aarch64 system, I have mounted the nano's `/usr/include/boost` into my build directory's `usr/include/boost`. Here's my build directory heirachy.

```
.
├── gcc-4.8.5-aarch64   #<cross compiler>
│   └── install
│       ├── aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
│        ...
├── opt                 #<ROS source files from nano>
│   └── ros
│       └── melodic
├── src                 #<test c++ code in here>
│   └── test_cpp
│       └── src
└── usr
    ├── include
    │   └── boost       #<nano's /usr/include/boost mounted in here>
    └── lib
        └── aarch64-linux-gnu  #<nano's /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu mounted in here>
```

When compiling, I get errors saying the compiler cannot find boost libraries.

```
from /home/teshan/xcompile/src/test_cpp/src/talker.cpp:1: /home/teshan/xcompile/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/time.h:58:50: 
fatal error: boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp: No such file or directory  
#include <boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp>
                                                 ^ 
compilation terminated.
```

I have `math/special_functions/round.hpp` file inside the mounted directory `usr/include/boost`. But it seems CMake cannot find it. Instead it says `boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp: No such file or directory` which I think indicates it searches for boost directory in the root directory (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016448/how-can-i-get-cmake-to-find-my-alternative-boost-installation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646405/how-do-you-add-boost-libraries-in-cmakelists-txt) answers but setting `BOOST_ROOT` does not seem to have an effect. Any insight to this would be of great help

---

**TL;DR**

This is my build script

```
#!/bin/bash

PWD=$(pwd)
export LANG=C
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash

catkin config --extend ${PWD}/opt/ros/melodic/

catkin build -j8 --cmake-args \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${PWD}/toolchain.cmake \
-DCMAKE_CROSS_COMPILE_PREFIX=${PWD} \
-DRT_LIBRARY=${PWD}/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/
```

---

Here's my toolchain.cmake

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${NANO_ROOT_PATH}/gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/bin/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${NANO_ROOT_PATH}/gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/bin/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++)

# Below call is necessary to avoid non-RT problem.
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE aarch64-linux-gnu)

SET(NANO_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
SET(NANO_MELODIC_PATH ${NANO_ROOT_PATH}/opt/ros/melodic)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${NANO_ROOT_PATH} ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX})
SET(COMPILER_ROOT ${NANO_ROOT_PATH}/gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install)

#Have to set this one to BOTH, to allow CMake to find rospack
#This set of variables controls whether the CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH and CMAKE_SYSROOT are used for find_xxx() operations.
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM BOTH)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${NANO_MELODIC_PATH} ${NANO_ROOT_PATH}/usr)

SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} --sysroot=${NANO_ROOT_PATH}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --sysroot=${NANO_ROOT_PATH}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS} --sysroot=${NANO_ROOT_PATH}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} --sysroot=${NANO_ROOT_PATH}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)

SET(LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${NANO_MELODIC_PATH}/lib)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

#Skip toolchain trying to build a test program first
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)

set(BOOST_ROOT ${NANO_ROOT_PATH}/usr/include/boost)

set(COMPILER_SYSROOT ${COMPILER_ROOT}/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot)
include_directories(BEFORE SYSTEM ${COMPILER_SYSROOT}/usr/include/)
```

Comment: "But it seems CMake cannot find it. Instead it says `boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp: No such file or directory`" - This message is from the **compiler**, not from CMake. All include directories, specified in `CMakeLists.txt` or toolchain are passed to the compiler. It seems you forgot to specify include directories for Boost. If you use `find_package(Boost)` or whatever equivalent in ROS, make sure it finds intended Boost.

Comment: In ROS, normally we do not specify boost directories for every package unless we use boost in our own code. Here boost is used by a ROS library. I was hoping it would find boost without asking like in a normal ROS package build. Still I do not know how to point the compiler / CMake to Boost. How do I show CMake the Boost path? (Just `find_package(Boost)` obviously gives me an error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved by mounting the whole `/usr/include` instead of `/usr/include/boost`. Compiler might have needed other files/ directories in `/usr/include` to look up Boost

```
.
├── gcc-4.8.5-aarch64   #<cross compiler>
│   └── install
│       ├── aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
│        ...
├── opt                 #<ROS source files from nano>
│   └── ros
│       └── melodic
├── src                 #<test c++ code in here>
│   └── test_cpp
│       └── src
└── usr
    ├── include         #<nano's /usr/include mounted in here>
    └── lib
        └── aarch64-linux-gnu  #<nano's /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu mounted in here>
```